# Resharper change default go to type for ctrl

Tags: resharper

currently when I hit ctrl and press mouse btn on type I got to type for example to interace , how can I change it to go to implementation ? I tried by tools, keyboard but can't change it key to ctrl + Left click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rebind the action that happens on ctrl+click. However, pressing alt+ctrl+click, you'll go to implementation. And ctrl+shift+click will open the result in the Peek Definition window.